# How to save and then load an instace of subclass for a property in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, classcastexception

We have a class User having a one-to-one relationship with a Preference (The property is called storedPreference). Suppose a user where an instance of CustomPreference (a subclass of Preference) is saved as its storedPreference. Getting storedPreference and casting it to CustomPreference leads to ClassCastException but why?

```
(CustomPreference)theUser.getStoredPreference()
```

causes

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: core.preferences.Preferences_$$_javassist_82 cannot be cast to hb.core.preferences.CustomPreferences
    at hb.base.user.user.HadithUser.getPreferences(HadithUser.java:39)
    at hb.base.user.user.HadithUser.getPreferences(HadithUser.java:23)
    at core.form.base.ThemeForm.getTheme(ThemeForm.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:587)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:517)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:298)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    ... 84 more
```

Here are entity definitions:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Preferences {
   ...
}


@Entity
public class CustomPreferences extends Preferences {
   ...
}


@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Preferences getStoredPreferences() {
        return storedPreferences;
    }

    ...
}
```

I checked the DB to ensure that DTYPE value for this instance is CustomPreference and it was correct

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JPA as such. This is plan java, a superclass reference can refer a subclass object, but a super class object cant be referenced by subclass.

```
(CustomPreference)theUser.getStoredPreference();
```

Preference object can be referred by Preference type or its super type but not by its subtype i.e. CustomPreference.And if you attempt to do so, it give ClassCasteException.

Comment: The object which is saved as storedPreference is a CustomPreference which is referenced through a superclass reference. So there should be no problem casting it back to subclass.